# "Constrained" Classification Problem

Tags: classification

I need to classify objects based on a set of features - typical classification settings. The additional information is that I know the number of individual which fall in a certain class.

In the sample I need to classify, I have N individuals that I need to classify in k classes. I do not know which individual falls in class C1, C2, ..., Ck  but I know the number of observations falling in each class. Can somebody please suggest a way to take this information into account?

Comment: Typically classificators based on Bayes rule take such a "constraint" into account, they call it prior probabilities for the classes. Of course a classification will usually violate this request to some degree; you could then re-classify some objects to a second closest class, to satisfy the request fully.

Comment: Thanks for this. Frankly my preference would have been to use tress with boosting but based on the reasoning of a priori distribution I had had a look at naive Bayes classifier indeed. I wonder if you could recommend a reference on the Bayes. I know nothing about it.

Comment: I personally am used to Discriminant Analysis which contains Bayes classifier as its second step, so you might read about DA